# I want to load all basic email data into an array, per each label

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-sheets

The object of my Google App Script is to log all incoming and outgoing emails for a given period of time, into a Google Spreadsheet at the end of the day or the week. The emails are received throughout the day and labeled as soon as they're addressed.

I started with simply logging the details of all messages currently in the inbox.

```
  // ** CREATE EMPTY DATA ARRAYS **
  var emailFrom = [];
  var emailTo = [];
  var emailBody = [];
  var emailDate = [];
  var emailLabel = [];
  var emailSubject = [];
  var emailLabel = [];

  // ** PUSH DATA INTO EMPTY ARRAYS **
  for(var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    emailBody.push(["  "]);    
    emailFrom.push([messages[i][0].getFrom()]);
    emailTo.push([messages[i][0].getTo()]);
    emailDate.push([messages[i][0].getDate()]);
    emailSubject.push([messages[i][0].getSubject()]);
  };

   // ** THEN, LOG THE FILLED DATA ARRAYS TO ROWS **
  // hint: getSheetValues(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns)
    mysheet.getRange(2,4,threads.length,1).setValues(emailFrom);
    mysheet.getRange(2,3,threads.length,1).setValues(emailTo);
    mysheet.getRange(2,1,threads.length,1).setValues(emailDate);
    mysheet.getRange(2,5,threads.length,1).setValues(emailSubject);
    mysheet.getRange(2,6,threads.length,1).setValues(emailBody);
```

However, most relevant email are stored in labels and I am having a hard time extracting these. Any time I try to set either 2 layers of loops: the first to loop through Label names, the second to get the threads from each Label, I either 
(a) Logger.log data that is useless

This

```
   for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
     var label = labels[i].getName();
     var labelObject = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label).getThreads();
     for (var t = 0; t < labelObject.length; i++){
       Logger.log(labelObject[t]);
     }
   }
```

Produces This

**Logging output:**

```
[14-11-19 19:51:19:283 CST] [GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread]
[14-11-19 19:51:19:385 CST] [GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread]
[14-11-19 19:51:23:932 CST] [GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread]
```

or I get various timeouts from Google.

**Message Details**

```
Service invoked too many times in a short time: gmail rateMax. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls.
```

or

`Exceeded maximum execution time Dismiss`

I am new to Google Script and haven't worked much with APIs in general. I wanted to make this utility to take care of some rote and programmable work I should be doing, and to learn a bit about javascript iterating in the process. It seems I will also learn a few things about service quotas.

Can anyone help me (a) solve this problem or (b) point me to a place I can learn how to approach this problem. Any resources will help, even if its some pointers on *HOW* to read the Google Script documentation.

link to full script -> **http://pastie.org/9732292**

Comment: Can you post the full script, or provide a link to it? I was glancing at this but you don't have 'threads' or 'messages' defined here, and I don't want to make assumptions about what you're doing.

Comment: Ahh, yeah. I placed a link at the bottom to a pastie containing the whole script. Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the good news is, you were definitely on the right track, but there was one or two errors you had made that was kicking you up here. First, a quick explanation of the error messages you were getting.

**Issue1:**

Why you were getting:

```
[14-11-19 19:51:19:283 CST] [GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread, GmailThread]
```

is because this line:

```
var labelObject = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label).getThreads();
```

Literally *was* just getting the thread. If you compare it to your line:

```
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
```

You can see what you were looking for is really something like:

```
var labelObject = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label).getThreads();
var labelMessages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(labelObject);
```

Which would get you the actual *message*, which is what you're looking for.

**Issue2:**

The reason you were getting:

```
Exceeded maximum execution time Dismiss
```

Is because you were exceeding the [maximum execution time of 6 minutes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) that each script can have. You probably noticed that your script was taking a long time to run, and then failing. Which is why you were getting 'Exceeded maximum execution time'.

The second:

```
Service invoked too many times in a short time: gmail rateMax. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls.
```

is a 'Rate limit' as the service is being called too many times, too fast. Normally you could slow things down a little, but that might not be necessary. If you continue to hit this when everything is working, ask a new question and we can talk about '[Utilities.sleep(1000)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep(Integer))'.

**Now that I've covered the error messages:**

The easiest way to explain how I've done it is probably to give you the code with comments:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {//Runs a for loop to get all the labels. 
     var label = labels[i].getName();//Gets the label name. 
     var labelObject = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label).getThreads();//Gets the threads in that label. 
    for (var j = 0; j <labelObject.length; j++){//Runs a for loop for all the threads in a label. 
     var labelMessages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(labelObject);//Gets the actual messages in the thread. 
    if (labelMessages[j] == undefined){// The label might be empty, so we have to tell it what to do if that's the case. 
    //Do nothing. 
    //Or log that it was undefined. 
    //I don't care, I'm a comment not a cop. 
    }else{//If it's not empty.
     emailBody.push(["  "]);    
     emailFrom.push([labelMessages[j][0].getFrom()]);
     emailTo.push([labelMessages[j][0].getTo()]);
     emailDate.push([labelMessages[j][0].getDate()]);
     emailSubject.push([labelMessages[j][0].getSubject()]);
    }
   }
  }
```

**Side Note:**

This would actually break your current value setting portion of your script:

```
   // ** THEN, LOG THE FILLED DATA ARRAYS TO ROWS **
  //getSheetValues(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns)
    mysheet.getRange(2,4,threads.length,1).setValues(emailFrom);
    mysheet.getRange(2,3,threads.length,1).setValues(emailTo);
    mysheet.getRange(2,1,threads.length,1).setValues(emailDate);
    mysheet.getRange(2,5,threads.length,1).setValues(emailSubject);
    mysheet.getRange(2,6,threads.length,1).setValues(emailBody);
```

As here you tell it that you want the number of rows to equal the 'threads.length', which worked up until now as the array lengths would be the same as the thread lengths, but now they won't be (As the number of threads in the inbox **and** the number of threads with labels have been added to the array). This is a simple fix, you want it to be equal to the length of the array:

```
mysheet.getRange(2,4,emailFrom.length,1).setValues(emailFrom);
mysheet.getRange(2,3,emailTo.length,1).setValues(emailTo);
mysheet.getRange(2,1,emailDate.length,1).setValues(emailDate);
mysheet.getRange(2,5,emailSubject.length,1).setValues(emailSubject);
mysheet.getRange(2,6,emailBody.length,1).setValues(emailBody);
```

(This is good practice anyway!)

In case you get stuck, the full code that I've modified can be found [here](http://pastie.org/private/0gbjj4rrxdnrrf0m0d6kq).

**A WORD OF CAUTION:**

Currently, the script is set to get ALL the messages in the inbox, and ALL the messages in your labels, so, basically, all of the messages in your account. *This will not work*, as the volume of messages are likely to be very high. Instead, you should get a **small** number of messages in your inbox **more frequently**, by using [a range for the 'getInboxThreads'](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getInboxThreads(Integer,Integer)) and setting your 'for' statement for the labels to only index some of the most recent messages, for example, instead of:

```
for (var j = 0; j <labelObject.length; j++)
```

You could set it to get the last 50 in each label:

```
 for (var j = 0; j < 50; j++)
```

If you continue to get the timeout or rate limit errors I talked about above, this is probably why, and you need to narrow the scope of what your indexing (Scripts won't be able to 'Get all' messages in your account if you have a lot of messages).

Comment: I will be able to look into this more after work. Looks incredibly helpful.

Comment: Incredibly helpful and thorough response my friend, very much appreciated. I now have the script logging the Labels as well. There's still a way to go but I can't thank you enough, you helped me over a hump.

Comment: Currently Lists Message Labels, Inbox, Full Time-stamps, and obviously Message Subject, To and From info
--> http://pastie.org/9734405